# Cannot Save Data Using Python Social Auth Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, python-social-auth

I'm trying to get the gender from a facebook login and save it into my database via Python Social Auth Django, I haven't been able to figure out why it keeps storing it as an empty string.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

views.py

```
def save_profile(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == 'facebook':
        sign_up = User.objects.get(username=user)
        sign_up.profile.gender = response.get('gender')
        sign_up.save()
```

settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id, name, email, picture,gender'}

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'accounts.views.save_profile',
)
```

Comment: First of all check, whether you are getting gender from facebook response or not ?

Comment: In admin page check the social user/auth model, in extra field it should be there

Comment: yes I can confirm response is showing it, and in the admin page it shows up blank as well

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `sign_up = User.objects.get(username=user)`, `user` is a `User` instance already. Also, verify that `gender` is part of that `response` object.